# How to Create a Persistent Notification with a Force Close button?

Tags: android, service, xamarin.forms, notifications, kill-process

I have a Xamarin Forms app that runs fine, but I need to implement a new feature similar to this [link.](https://cdn.arstechnica.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/15.jpg)

I need to create a notification for the app that persists as long as the app is running. There should be a "force kill" button in the notification. Similar to how Google Maps allows the user to 'end navigation' or some music player apps allow the user to control the music from a notification bar.

Can anyone tell me where to begin, or what resources I can check?

Here is a little background of the problem we're facing. We have an app that can create a WebRTC stream. The user can mirror cast their Android device to a screen. Now if they decide to "Swipe Recent" to close the app, the WebRTC service does not get destroyed. The user should use "Force Close" from App Info to truly end their stream. If they don't, they might assume that their Swipe Recent action had closed the app, along with the mirror cast stream, while in fact it is still streaming their screen. This happens on select few Android 8 devices.

We're thinking that perhaps a Notification bar similar to the screenshot will persist even after the app had been swiped from the Recents list, until the user decides to truly terminate the app and its WebRTC service from the notification area.

Thank you.

Comment: It seems like your problem should be fixing the fact that a swipe away form the recents doesn't close everything, not hacking in a button to do so in the notification.  That's the bad user experience.

Comment: So you only want the stream to work while the Activity is running? Why not just stop the Service in the `onDestroy()` method of your Activity?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've tried that, but OnDestroy() doesn't get called when the app is closed. Neither do Finish(), FinishAndRemoveTask(), Dispose(), or the finalizer... The only one that gets called is OnStop(), but that gets called when the app is minimized. I should only terminate the app when the app is swiped from recents, not when the user goes to the desktop.